# Wix Localization fails for WixIIsExtension,

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix-extension

i am trying create my setup for localization support, i got below error while build

Error   17  The localization variable !(loc.msierrIISCannotConnect) is unknown.  Please ensure the variable is defined.

i won't get above error while i add en-US in culture, but when i add another culture es-ES then above error comes.

please help me how to fix this error

Answer (score -1):

It means that locale has not defined that string which is used someplace in the WixIIsExtension.  So, you can define it in a wxl file for your es-ES locale (you probably have such a file already based on your question).

I was trying to create a neutral locale installer so that I don't have the installer put into an en-US directory in my TargetOutput directory.  In other words, I want to see bin\debug\installer.msi and not bin\debug\en-us\installer.msi.  The neutral locale has hundreds of these missing strings.  I defined them all as empty in my wxl file with some help from regex replace-all.  But, solving this problem, I now get missing bitmaps as encountered by light.exe.  For example:

`E:\delivery\Dev\wix36_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ExitDialog.wxs(19,0): error   LGHT0204: ICE17: Bitmap: '' for Control: 'Bitmap' of Dialog: 'ExitDialog' not found in Binary table`

For the neutral locale, there are about 25 of these.  I don't know about es-ES, or if these are added, what else would be missing.

It looks like these need to be completed in the WiX code itself for the non en-US locales for WixIIsExtension.